# Invalid Jump errors

Tags: solidity, testrpc

This is my project and I keep running into Invalid Jump errors whenever trying to call anything other than the Project.getName(). For example, running Project.getAddress(), Project.getAmount(), and Project.deadline() always throw the Invalid Jump. I initially tried to have all of these details log to console with one function, and have broken it down individually to confirm these issues.

I'm running testrpc, and wondering if this could have something to do with gas, despite these functions being constants that wouldn't require any gas. Thanks.

FundingHub.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

import "Project.sol";

contract FundingHub {

    address public owner;
    address[] public projectAddresses;

    modifier onlyOwner() { if (msg.sender != owner) throw; _; }

    function FundingHub() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function createProject(string name, uint248 amountToRaise, uint248 deadline) returns (address) {
        address newProject = new Project(name, amountToRaise, deadline);
        projectAddresses.push(newProject);
        return newProject;
    }

    function getProjectAddress(uint i) constant returns (address projectAddress) {
        return projectAddresses[i];
    }

    function killMe() onlyOwner returns (bool successful) {
        suicide(owner);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Project.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

contract Project {

    struct projectInfo {
        address projectOwner;
        string name;
        uint248 amountToRaise;
        uint248 deadline;
    }

    projectInfo public info;

    function Project(string name, uint248 amountToRaise, uint248 deadline) {
        info = projectInfo(tx.origin, name, amountToRaise, deadline);
    }

    /*
    function getInfo() public constant returns (address, string, uint248, uint248) {
        return (info.projectOwner, info.name, info.amountToRaise, info.deadline);
    }
    */

    //Only this function works
    function getName() public constant returns (string) {
        return info.name;
    }

    function getOwner() public constant returns (address) {
        return info.projectOwner;
    }

    function getAmount() public constant returns (uint248) {
        return info.amountToRaise;
    }

    function getDeadline() public constant returns (uint248) {
        return info.deadline;
    }
}
```

Javascript functions

```
function createProject(name, amountToRaise, deadline) {
    hub.createProject(name, amountToRaise, deadline, {from: account, gas: 3000000}).then(function(txn) {
        return getTransactionReceiptMined(txn);
    })
};

//Doesn't work
function getProjectOwner(i) {
    hub.getProjectAddress(i).then(function(value) {
        console.log(value);
        project = Project.at(value);
        project.getOwner().then(function(value) {
            console.log(value);
        });
    });
}

//Works
function getProjectName(i) {
    hub.getProjectAddress(i).then(function(value) {
        console.log(value);
        project = Project.at(value);
        project.getName().then(function(value) {
            console.log(value);
        });
    });
}
```

Here's the console output:
[image: Console output]

Comment: Works fine for me in browser solidity. Are you sure it's not an issue with your "hub" returning the wrong address?

Comment: Yes, we need to see your Hub code.

Comment: To add to @TjadenHess's comment, try examining the address with web3.eth.getCode(). If there's no code, that would explain an invalid jump. (IIRC that's the error it gives in that situation, but I may be wrong.)

Comment: I added the code and the console output.
Yes, it works fine in browser solidity, that's why I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I also made the javascript functions getProjectAmount and getProjectDeadline, but they return the same error.

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure about it, can you give me the following ouput of this: `project.getOwner.call().then(function(value) {            console.log(value);
        });`

Comment: Same thing: `Unhandled rejection Error: Error: VM Exception while executing eth_call: invalid JUMP at`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but removing "public" from all the functions in Project.sol solved the problem.